# Why the flash screen in many Android apps is not closed when the back button is clicked?

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, android-activity, splash-screen

For example, when you open WhatsApp, during the launch of the app, the splash activity is on the screen. If the user changed his mind and preferred to close the app, the app does not close! He must wait till the app launch and the splash activity disappear … This is almost the case in all Google's Android apps that I have used … How to implement this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because they overried the onBackPressed() method (in splash screen activity)

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        //super.onBackPressed()
}
```

and comment the super.onBackPressed()

you can add logical condition there to decide wheatear to go back or not

```
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if(condtion is true)
            super.onBackPressed()
        else
           Log.e("","process pending")
    }
```

if u MainActivity takes 3 sec to load launch SplachScreenActivity.class
and block it for 3 sec using thread or timer once timer expiries call finish() method which will get back to MainActivity where u find MainActivty ready

Comment: This is incorrect, a splash screen is displayed before your application code has been initialized, the activity is not yet created so this method would not be called. See my answer for how they really do it, using a themed launcher activity.

Comment: are u sure..? splash screen is just a basic activity which will present in front of user for some specific time period to make sure that out main actvity get loaded properly. now since Splash screen is a activity u can override onBackPressed() and disable go-back option

Comment: Most applications don't add a deliberate slowdown to their start-up time. The splash screens all big apps use, are displayed during the initialization of the Application class, they're not adding them in on purpose. Android just gives us a way to do very basic styling of this screen, by setting a static background image on it and changing the background color. It is an alternative to there being a white screen for a second while the app is initializing. You can add a second loading screen, the kind that you're suggesting after this first one is finished loading.

Comment: @abhijithmogaveera .. Actually both of you are right. Yes, the best practice is to load the splash screen as theme for an empty activity. This makes it available once the user clicks on the launcher icon. And this is the objective of the splash screens, you want to give the user something to look at while the heavy activities of your app are starting up. So, you should not be solving the problem with another heavy activity that itself will take time to launch. So, an empty activity that holds little logic and doesn't even inflate a layout is the best to go.

Comment: @TomášBeňo .. But here is the missing part in your answer. Using an empty activity with a theme as the splash screen does not make it dummy! .. It is still an activity which means that if I clicked on the back button, it would close. If I rotated the screen, it would rotate. So, I should also be overriding the onBackPressed() function to prevent that from happening. And I should fix the orientation of the screen from the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @MohammedSharafEddeen For me, it prevents orientation change and closing the app, just by using the theme, without having any code in the activity whatsoever. The activity does not exist at all while the app is starting, android is just being nice and applying it's theme onto a blank view that is not part of any activity.

Comment: @TomášBeňo .. I am testing on a real device, but I have to mention that its SDK version is old. So maybe, you are right. However, I still disagree with you when you say that the activity does not exist .. Only the layout does not exist. In your code, you were extending from AppCompatActivity Class. So, it is an activity and it does exist.

Comment: What you're actually seeing as the splash screen, is not the SplashActivity, the system just creates a blank view that fills the screen, and reads the windowBackground attribute from that activity's theme. The SplashActivity will only be created after this splash screen is gone, after the app is loaded. Then the code within your activity will be executed, but no sooner than that.

Comment: an light weight activity can mimic Splash screen, and the question he asked is how to prevent an user going back while splash screen is active

Answer (score 1):

They're using a trick. The splash screen is actually just a theme on a dummy activity, which lets them render a static background drawable while the application is still being created by the system. This means you can't actually have any logic running, nor can you create any views on a splash screen, it is just a static image.

**res/values/themes.xml**

I believe `android:windowBackground` is the only attribute that will be accepted for a splash screen.

```xml
<resources>

  <style name="AppTheme_Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

**res/drawable/splash_screen.xml**

In my example, I display two .png images on the splash screen.

```xml
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="@color/splash_screen_background" />
    </shape>
  </item>

  <item>
    <bitmap
        android:antialias="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_logo"
        android:tileMode="disabled" />
  </item>

  <item>
    <bitmap
        android:antialias="true"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_logo_title"
        android:tileMode="disabled" />
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

Apply the theme `@style/AppTheme_Splash`, and add `MAIN` and `LAUNCHER` intent-filters.

```xml
<manifest>
  <application
      android:name=".BaseApplication"
      android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
      android:label="@string/launcher_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme_Light">

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme_Splash">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" />

  </application>
</manifest>
```

**SplashActivity.java**

The `onCreate` method will be executed after the application is fully loaded. No logic is executed until that point, nor would the activity's View be rendered until after the app is loaded.

```java
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(homeIntent);
    finish();
  }
}
```

I think that's it!